# Making my own filter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make my own filter in `angularjs`, but the  way what i do is wrong i guess. but i am not able to get what left here and need to update.

any one help me to fix this?, I guess i need to convert this filter as a service? if so what is the correct way to do this?

my js :

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
angular.module('myApp.filters', [])
.filter('capitalize', function(capitalize) {
    return function(input) {
    if (input)
    return input[0].toUpperCase() +
    input.slice(1);
    }
});
```

html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  {{ "San Francisco is very cloudy" | lowercase | capitalize  }}
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jt8atto4/)

Comment: Your function does not always return a value.  What if `!input`?  This may not be the main problem, but it could be a problem.

Comment: What's your desired output ?

Comment: I would like to create my own filter. here i tried to create a `capitalize`, which will capitalize the first letter alone

Comment: Remove the second line (= do not define another module) and it [should work](http://jsfiddle.net/d08z0rtv/).

Comment: The bootstrap module (here `myApp`) needs to depend on the other (`myApp.filters`) for the services provided by the second to be active. So make it: `angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters']);`

Answer (score 3):

Your filter has one issue, not sure if that's what you meant - but in your function you have `function(capitalize)` which makes Angular believe you have a service/factory of that name. If that's something you have somewhere then fine, but it also doesn't seem like you're using it.

You can open your Dev console and see if you see any errors - my guess is that you will.

Removing it makes it work:

```
myApp.filter('capitalize', function() {
    return function(input) {
        if (input)
            return input[0].toUpperCase() + input.slice(1);
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12424/)

Comment: most of the people make this mistake at the first

Comment: @JhonSmith Yes, Angular makes you learn many things the hard way.